# Zend search form, navigate to external site via controller

Tags: php, forms, redirect, search, zend-framework

I have question to You. I am working and fixing little bugs on website built on Zend framework. We have search form indented for searching through services, products and companies. Search form has three radio buttons to select: **services**, **product**, **companies**.

All of these search query are transfered to ListController.php

I need addiotional radio button with label "Articles" and I need to redirect 
search form to

> www.example.com/**s?=SEARCH TEXT**

I don't know If i need to make module in my ListController.php or change my approach.

Code for input text:

```
<input type="text" id="search" class="searchfield" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['search'])): ?><?= $_GET['search']; ?><?php else: ?>Search for product, company and services... <?php endif; ?>"> <a class="searchbutton" onclick="#" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
```

Another code:

```
<?php if(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName()!='user'): ?>
<?php if(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='list' || Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='companies' || Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='products'){$small='-small';}else{$small='';} ?>

<?php $defSearch = 'products'; if(isset($_GET['search'])): ?>

<?php if(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='list'){

    if(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName()=='services') {
        $defSearch = 'services';
    }

if(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName()=='companies') {
    $defSearch = 'companies';
}

} ?>
```

Radio button value:

```
 <div class="searchradio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" <?php if($defSearch=='products'): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> id="q156" name="type" value="product" /> Product
            </label> 
            <label>
                <input type="radio" <?php if($defSearch=='companies'): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> id="q157" name="type" value="company" /> Company
            </label> 
            <label>
                <input type="radio" <?php if($defSearch=='services'): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> id="q158" name="type" value="services" /> Services
            </label>
```

I need to do this all through ListController.php ? Or can I make IF statent on input value something like this:

```
<form method=get action="http://example.com">
<input type=text name=q? value="">
<input type=submit value="lets go">
</form>
```

Kind Regards